# Final form of transfer function in a single input single output system

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory, transfer-function

I am reading the textbook "Modern Control Engineering" by Katsuhiko Ogata. There is a section on deriving the transfer function from the state space equations dx/dt = Ax + Bu and
y = Cx + Du

After taking Laplace Transforms and some simplification, we get G(s) = C(sI - A)^-1 B + D which is fine.

How this then turns into G(s) = Q(s) / |sI - A| stumps me. Here, Q(s) is a polynomial in s.

Can anyone help out?

Comment: Start by showing what you have tried - someone may then point out an error or something.

Comment: What is the expression for $Q(s)$? Expressing the inverse of a matrix (in this case $(sI-A)$) usually involves the determinant of the same matrix (in this case $|sI-A|$).

Answer (score 0):

I think I was able to figure this out by referring to https://eng.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Industrial_and_Systems_Engineering/Book%3A_Dynamic_Systems_and_Control_(Dahleh_Dahleh_and_Verghese)/12%3A_Modal_decomposition_of_state-space_models/12.01%3A_The_Transfer_Function_Matrix.